# Proving $\pi(x) > c \ln(x)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given:

a) Every integer can be factored into the product of a square-free number (one not divisible by the square of a prime) and a perfect square;

b) If there exist exactly r primes, then there exist exactly $2^r$ square-free numbers; and

c) $n>2^r\sqrt{n}$, prove that $\pi(x) > c \ln{x}$ for some absolute constant $c$.

I am pretty stumped here, so any advice would be appreciated! I started trying to do it with the knowledge that $\ln{x} < x$, but couldn't figure out how to bring in $\pi(x)$.

Edit: I have proven parts a and b, just looking for some advice on part c.

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: Since there exist infinitely many primes, b) is an instance of *ex falso sequitur quodlibet*. Can't understand c) since for me $r=\infty$.  For large $x$, however, we must have $\pi(x)>c\log x$ since $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$ and $x/\log x$ grows faster than $\log x$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Elementary Number Theory by George Andrews

Answer (score 1):

a) follows from unique factorization: suppose we have $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_j^{a_j}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes and the $a_i$ are integers $\ge1$.  Then either an $a_i$ is even, so $p_i^{a_i}$ is a perfect square $=(p_i^{a_i/2})^2$, or it's odd in which case $p_i^{a_i-1}$ is a perfect square $=(p_i^{(a_i-1)/2})^2$ (or $1$ if $a_i=1$).

Let $O\subset \{1, 2, \ldots, j\}$ be the set of indices $i$ for which $a_i$ is odd. If $O=\emptyset$ then $n$ is a perfect square and we are done.  Otherwise we have $n'=\prod_{i\in O} p_i$ square-free, and $n/n'$ a product of perfect squares.

Perhaps b) means "if you are given $r$ primes, then there are exactly $2^r-1$ square-free numbers divisible by one or more of these primes."

Comment: It should be $2^r$ for b) because $1$ is also square-free number.

Comment: Umm, but $1$ is not divisible by any prime.